# patterns/patterns for designer-webdeveloper communication

Tags: javascript

as the title implies i am searching for a good pattern / schema collection that makes designer <-> webdeveloper communication less ambiguous when it comes to javascript effects and dynamic content loading.

google just provided me with the shorthand markup by ryan singer, but this seems to be restricted to page/ui flows.

can you recommend any commonly used / efficient patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [yahoo patterns repository](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/)?

Answer (score 0):

A goal for site implementation should be to minimize your on-page scripting. People call that "unobtrusive Javascript" or something like that.  In order to do that, page elements will need some markup for your script code to look for anyway. In other words, if you want to have a "div" that fades in after the page loads, well then you might add to its "class" value something like "fadeIn fadeSpeed:slow".  Your script code will look for such things and perform animations (or whatever).

Well the point is that as you set up such a framework, you'll naturally end up with a way for the designer to communicate intention. You'll have to come up with a "vocabulary" of page dynamic elements, but you'd hopefully do that anyway. Once that's done, then the very thing that the markup will need to actually make the dynamic effects happen will serve as the designer's vehicle for indicating design intentions.

Another useful tool for such things is the development of your own custom tags, something that varies between difference server platforms. Such tags can "wrap" certain messy markup tasks and, again, capture the agreed-upon site elements that implement an overall design theme.

Comment: thanks for your answer - my question though has nothing to do with unobtrusive js (this is a requirement anyway because of seo reasons)

the vocabulary of page dynamics is exactly what i am looking for because we don't want to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Well, there are all sorts of things that you *can* do on a page (with CSS and/or Javascript). What you *will* do on your own site has to be something developers and designers work out. Ideally, that's a sort of "meta-design" process, and of course it'll mature as the actual design matures. The point is that it's good to determine up front what meanings you want to associate with color choice, layouts, borders, fonts, form elements, text blocks, error messages, etc etc etc. Dynamic behaviors are just part of that. I think it's something that should be "home grown."